# Download file from Express server

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to download file from my Express server. I'm sure the file is in a good location. It doesn't get errors, but the file is not downloaded anyway.

NodeJS:

```
const DOWNLOAD_FOLDER = 'downloads'
const IMAGES_FOLDER = 'images'

const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')


const app = express()
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, async (req, resp, next) => {    
  const filename = `test_file.zip`
  const downloadUrl = `./${DOWNLOAD_FOLDER}/${filename}.zip`
  
  if (fs.existsSync(downloadUrl)) {
    resp.download(`${__dirname}/${downloadUrl}`, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log('success')
      }
    })
  }
})


app.listen(5000).setTimeout(500000)
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
```

In the console, I see a console log("success"), but my browser doesn't download file.

React:

```
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 'url': data.url})
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('data', data)
      setLoading(false)
      setData({ url: '' })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw new Error(err)
    })
  }
```

Comment: In this line: `const filename = \`shutterstock_${url.match(urlIdPattern)}\` ` I can not see where `url` and `urlIdPattern` are coming from. Could you clarify this in the example?

Comment: We can assume that the name is constant, e.g. test_file.zip

Comment: Do you want the user of the react application to download the file via their browser?

Comment: @frankenapps, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to make a fetch request. You might request only the URL by requesting the route with file name to be resolved via express. On client side you set the following:

```
window.location = `http://localhost:5000/${data.url}`
```

On the express side you change the method from `post` to `get`. You have to keep though the logic as to see the route and the file to be resolved dynamically.

Edit:
Solution with fetch. It is also necessary to instruct the browser to download the file, e.g. by setting `window.location`

```
fetch(url).then(r => r.blob())
.then(img => {
  imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(img)
  window.location = imgURL;
})
```

Comment: On server-side, I dynamically create files, so before sending a request file doesn't exist.
Does that mean I can't download the file if I use POST?

Comment: When I send POST request via Postman and save a result as a file I get a correct file from server.

Comment: I updated my answer with a `fetch` get example. Of course this would be possible with POST as well, but it is not logical. The REST verbs are intended to describe the action. As I understand it is intended to `get` an image. `post` is the opposite.